# iOS 6 Screen Size/Orientation Issues & GLES1.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es, ios6

I am having some trouble with Size/Orientation issues with my GLES1.1 app. Prior to iOS 6.0 everything was fine and it only occurs when I build with iOS 6.0 FOR an iOS 6.0 updated device. Which indicates its some changes with the libraries.

I have noticed there have been changes to the device orientation, I have resolved this issue and the messages are being received fine. I can rotate the device.

The main issue im having is that now the screen size is scaled upwards (in GLES1.1). Im not sure if the viewport is the issue or maybe the aspect ratio. The touch positions for the app are fine, if I play a movie with MPMoviePlayerController, that's fine, I have overlayed some images onto this movie (using UIImage) which is fine. But anything rendered with GLES1.1 is now scaled and I cant pin point the issue.

Im searching for a major change to the libraries that may have caused this issue, I have still yet to find a solution although I have heard of very similar problems (mainly with Cocos2d) I still havent found a correct solution.

Any advice for those with similar problems would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I fixed it by re-writing my code to not use an XIB file.

Comment: Probably what happened was your view was resized after the frame buffer was created. You should recreate it in such cases.

Comment: How can catch this case?

Comment: You can override "-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame" methode in your GL view class